# What materials absorb water and release it steadily when compressed?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, materials, design

Absorbent cotton wool is a good bio-compatible example, but it has low availability in the US and is not reusable.

Comment: A sponge is another example.

Answer (score 2):

reticulated (i.e., open-celled) foams of polyurethane are excellent for this purpose, and commercially available in bulk. their nominal pore sizes can be specified as well.